# Is there a faster way to calculate Cook's distance with R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, rcpp, lm

My task is to remove outliers from the grouped data frame of approx. 3.500.000 rows and to perform a linear fit on each group after that. I have already found a way to speed up my linear fit by using the `fastLmPure` function from the **RcppEigen** package instead of `lm` from **stats**, which made my calculations like >100x faster.

On the other hand, the `cooks.distance` function I'm  using only works together with `lm` or `glm`, which means that I can't use either `fastLmPure` or `fastLm` outputs to calculate outliers (at least directly).

This is the formula I'm using at the moment to calculate Cook's distance:

```
df %>%
   mutate(cooks_dist = cooks.distance(lm(y ~ x + 1)))
```

The code above needs ~45 minutes to process the said data frame, while `fastLmPure`'s fit is done within 15 seconds.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, yes I did. But maybe I've missed something.

Comment: I had that wrong, and removed the earlier comment. So here you want the usual tricks: i) a faster regression method than `lm()` (which you have), ii) maybe thinking hard about which parts if any of the regressor matriix are fixed iii) rewrite the distance calculation to take residuals from _e.g._ `fastLm()` and iv) faster grouping (for which I like `data.table`).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thank you! Will try this approach

Comment: Oh, and v) Don't use a formula!  They slow things down. Stick with `fastLmPure` _i.e._ matrix and vector if you can.